# The site can't be reached the local server says on visual studio code

Tags: laravel, visual-studio-code, server, laravel-artisan

I have downloaded a laravel code from github migrated everything. Now the problem is it works perfectly fine if I run the website through the link i.e http://localhost/ecom_proj/public/. But when I start server by PHP artisan serve on visual studio code. The link http://127.0.0.1:8000 doesn't work and the page says the site can't be reached.And Ctrl+C command also doesn't work to end the server. Help me plz I'm new to this

Answer (score 0):

try running `composer install` commmand.

Comment: still says the site can't be reached.

Answer (score 0):

If you successfully downloaded or clone form github, and run these command -

```
php -r "file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');"
composer install
php artisan key:generate
```

Then apache server restart. I hope it will be work.

Comment: still not working. It only works if I go through the direct link that is http://localhost/proj/laravel-ecommerce/public/.

Comment: I have tried on two different projects by cloning from github.

Comment: When you run command in terminal 'php artisan serve' then what error shown? please tell me?

Comment: [Thu Dec 10 12:56:17 2020] PHP 7.4.5 Development Server (http://127.0.0.1:8000) started
[Thu Dec 10 12:56:28 2020] 127.0.0.1:52543 Accepted
[Thu Dec 10 12:56:28 2020] 127.0.0.1:52544 Accepted
[Thu Dec 10 12:56:28 2020] PHP Warning:  Unknown: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0